# Flutter stateleswidget returning a list

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm moving what I previously had in a function into a stateless widget. I was wondering if I could return a list with a type of Widget, if so how would I go about doing this?

I've tried some random stuff that only further broke my app.

```
class returnList1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return <Widget>[
      InfoCard(),
      InfoCard(),
      InfoCard(),
      Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
            iconSize:
                35.0, // TODO: scale icons based on mediaquery height and width
            color: Colors.black,
            onPressed: () {
              print("More Pressed!");
            },
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.034,
                MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02839,
                0.0,
                0.0),
            child: Material(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              elevation: 7.5,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(200.0),
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.009675,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.0559,
                color: Colors.transparent,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
    ];
  }
}
```

When I run the code, I get "the getter 'length' was called on null. In my IDE, I get "The return type 'List' isn't a 'Widget', as defined by the method 'build'."

Comment: That won't work. You would need to wrap the content in a widget that takes a list of widgets before you return it (like a `Column`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't return a List with `build` method. `build` method can only return a `Widget`.
If you want return a List then you create a function and return a List which can be used in children property of any Multiple Child Container.

Here's the code.

```
    _returnList (BuildContext context) {
    return [
      InfoCard(),
      InfoCard(),
      InfoCard(),
      Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
            iconSize:
            35.0, // TODO: scale icons based on mediaquery height and width
            color: Colors.black,
            onPressed: () {
              print("More Pressed!");
            },
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.034,
                MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02839,
                0.0,
                0.0),
            child: Material(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              elevation: 7.5,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(200.0),
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.009675,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.0559,
                color: Colors.transparent,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
    ];
  }
```